# The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

Tags: remote-access, moodle

We have configured moodle application connection using remote Database.I'm getting Database connection error. When i'm use localhost instead of remote ip its working. Can anybody  help. Thanks in advance.
the below is my config.php file

[image: $CFG->dbtype = 'mysqli'; $CFG->dblibrary = 'native'; $CFG->dbhost = '3.92.37.127'; $CFG->dbname = 'rtalms'; $CFG->dbuser = 'rta_user'; $CFG->dbpass = 'AbZyyh546^%paSS'; $CFG->prefix = 'mdl_'; $CFG->dboptions = array ( 'dbpersist' => 0,]

Answer (score 0):

To use a remote database, you'll need to set this value in `config.php`

```
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';  // eg 'localhost' or 'db.isp.com' or IP
```

See `config-dist.php` in your Moodle folder for details

```
//=========================================================================
// 1. DATABASE SETUP
//=========================================================================
// First, you need to configure the database where all Moodle data       //
// will be stored.  This database must already have been created         //
// and a username/password created to access it.                         //

$CFG->dbtype    = 'pgsql';      // 'pgsql', 'mariadb', 'mysqli', 'auroramysql', 'sqlsrv' or 'oci'
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';     // 'native' only at the moment
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';  // eg 'localhost' or 'db.isp.com' or IP
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';     // database name, eg moodle
$CFG->dbuser    = 'username';   // your database username
$CFG->dbpass    = 'password';   // your database password
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';       // prefix to use for all table names
$CFG->dboptions = array(
    'dbpersist' => false,       // should persistent database connections be
                                //  used? set to 'false' for the most stable
                                //  setting, 'true' can improve performance
                                //  sometimes
    'dbsocket'  => false,       // should connection via UNIX socket be used?
                                //  if you set it to 'true' or custom path
                                //  here set dbhost to 'localhost',
                                //  (please note mysql is always using socket
                                //  if dbhost is 'localhost' - if you need
                                //  local port connection use '127.0.0.1')
    'dbport'    => '',          // the TCP port number to use when connecting
                                //  to the server. keep empty string for the
                                //  default port
    'dbhandlesoptions' => false,// On PostgreSQL poolers like pgbouncer don't
                                // support advanced options on connection.
                                // If you set those in the database then
                                // the advanced settings will not be sent.
    'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', // MySQL has partial and full UTF-8
                                // support. If you wish to use partial UTF-8
                                // (three bytes) then set this option to
                                // 'utf8_unicode_ci', otherwise this option
                                // can be removed for MySQL (by default it will
                                // use 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'. This option should
                                // be removed for all other databases.
    // 'fetchbuffersize' => 100000, // On PostgreSQL, this option sets a limit
                                // on the number of rows that are fetched into
                                // memory when doing a large recordset query
                                // (e.g. search indexing). Default is 100000.
                                // Uncomment and set to a value to change it,
                                // or zero to turn off the limit. You need to
                                // set to zero if you are using pg_bouncer in
                                // 'transaction' mode (it is fine in 'session'
                                // mode).
    /*
    'connecttimeout' => null, // Set connect timeout in seconds. Not all drivers support it.
    'readonly' => [          // Set to read-only slave details, to get safe reads
                             // from there instead of the master node. Optional.
                             // Currently supported by pgsql and mysqli variety classes.
                             // If not supported silently ignored.
      'instance' => [        // Readonly slave connection parameters
        [
          'dbhost' => 'slave.dbhost',
          'dbport' => '',    // Defaults to master port
          'dbuser' => '',    // Defaults to master user
          'dbpass' => '',    // Defaults to master password
        ],
        [...],
      ],

    Instance(s) can alternatively be specified as:

      'instance' => 'slave.dbhost',
      'instance' => ['slave.dbhost1', 'slave.dbhost2'],
      'instance' => ['dbhost' => 'slave.dbhost', 'dbport' => '', 'dbuser' => '', 'dbpass' => ''],

      'connecttimeout' => 2, // Set read-only slave connect timeout in seconds. See above.
      'latency' => 0.5,      // Set read-only slave sync latency in seconds.
                             // When 'latency' seconds have lapsed after an update to a table
                             // it is deemed safe to use readonly slave for reading from the table.
                             // It is optional. If omitted once written to a table it will always
                             // use master handle for reading.
                             // Lower values increase the performance, but setting it too low means
                             // missing the master-slave sync.
      'exclude_tables' => [  // Tables to exclude from read-only slave feature.
          'table1',          // Should not be used, unless in rare cases when some area of the system
          'table2',          // is malfunctioning and you still want to use readonly feature.
      ],                     // Then one can exclude offending tables while investigating.

    More info available in lib/dml/moodle_read_slave_trait.php where the feature is implemented.
    ]
     */
// For all database config settings see https://docs.moodle.org/en/Database_settings
);
```